# gazebo_worlds crashes on startup

Tags: ros, startup, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the gazebo_worlds installation and run instructions and the screen popped up for one second and went away. I've included the original error & diagnostic info below. I also included glxinfo.

I have an Intel video card. Not sure if it's compatible. Glxinfo says it's Opengl DRI. Glxgears runs fine.

Ubunto Oneiric - Ros Electric

---

```
bill@bill-Inspiron-620:~$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch

... logging to /home/bill/.ros/log/29ced732-0a6b-11e1-ac3b-3859f9411c72/roslaunch-bill-Inspiron-620-4459.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://bill-Inspiron-620:58288/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time
 * /rosdistro

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4473]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 29ced732-0a6b-11e1-ac3b-3859f9411c72
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4486]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [4500]
G    azebo multi-robot simulator, version 0.10.0

Part of the Player/Stage Project [http://playerstage.sourceforge.net].
Copyright (C) 2003 Nate Koenig, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the GNU General Public License.

directory [/tmp/gazebo-bill-0] already exists (previous crash?)
the owner gazebo server (pid=4406) is not running.
deleting the old information of the directory [/tmp/gazebo-bill-0]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 4500, exit code -6].
log files: /home/bill/.ros/log/29ced732-0a6b-11e1-ac3b-3859f9411c72/gazebo-2*.log
```

---

```
bill@bill-Inspiron-620:~$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds debug.launch

... logging to /home/bill/.ros/log/3977c87a-0a6a-11e1-a3f3-3859f9411c72/roslaunch-bill-Inspiron-620-4361.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://bill-Inspiron-620:50619/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time
 * /rosdistro

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4375]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 3977c87a-0a6a-11e1-a3f3-3859f9411c72
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4388]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [4401]
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.3-0ubuntu2) 7.3-2011.08
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/bin/gazebo...done.
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 0.10.0

Part of the Player/Stage Project [http://playerstage.sourceforge.net].
Copyright (C) 2003 Nate Koenig, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the GNU General Public License.

[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0xb022fb70 (LWP 4414)]
[New Thread 0xafa2eb70 (LWP 4415)]
[New Thread 0xaf22db70 (LWP 4416)]
[New Thread 0xaea2cb70 (LWP 4417)]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
directory [/tmp/gazebo-bill-0] already exists (previous crash?)
the owner gazebo server (pid=4325) is not running.
deleting the old information of the directory [/tmp/gazebo-bill-0]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb7fdf424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7fdf424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb792ac8f in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb792e2b5 in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb7b494ed in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
   from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0xb7b47283 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0xb7b472bf in std::terminate() ()
   from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0xb7b4740e in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0xb75bc0d9 in libgazebo::IfaceFactory::NewIface(std::string const&) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo.so.0.10.0
#8  0xb7d1849f in gazebo::Factory::Factory() ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#9  0xb7ceb82c in gazebo::World::Load(gazebo::XMLConfigNode*, int) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#10 0xb7d13782 in gazebo::Simulator::Load(gazebo::XMLConfig*, int) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#11 0xb7d14684 in gazebo::Simulator::LoadWorldFile(std::string const&, int) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_se---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
rver.so.0.10.0
#12 0x080a563a in main (argc=135590252, argv=0x823dbac)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.7/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/gazeboros.cpp:2572
(gdb)
```

---

```
bill@bill-Inspiron-620:~$ glxinfo

name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11858/gazebo_worlds-crashes-on-startup/) by [Bill OBryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1339/bill-obryan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try turning on Debug information for Gazebo by editing the CMakeLists.txt and Makefile.tarball and check whether your crash corresponds with https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5170. This should be solved in the latest electric version at  https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/electric

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill OBryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1339/bill-obryan/) on 2011-11-28**:
The latest update of Gazebo_worlds fixed the problem. thanks.